# Is it possible to activate Kafka-Streams EOS for producer only?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I wonder if it possible to configure a KafkaStream configuration with an EOS only on producer part.
I have a topic source with no transaction and no commit set by a producer (producer is a librdkafka one that don't implement transactional support yet).

I want to use KafkaStream on this topic with a EOS producer (transaction + commit) and i don't think it possible yet because of this part:

```
final Map tempConsumerDefaultOverrides = new HashMap(CONSUMER_DEFAULT_OVERRIDES);
tempConsumerDefaultOverrides.put(ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, READ_COMMITTED.name().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
CONSUMER_EOS_OVERRIDES = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempConsumerDefaultOverrides);

if (CONSUMER_EOS_OVERRIDES.containsKey(config)) {
    if (!clientProvidedProps.get(config).equals(CONSUMER_EOS_OVERRIDES.get(config))) {
        log.warn(String.format(nonConfigurableConfigMessage, "consumer", config, eosMessage, clientProvidedProps.get(config), CONSUMER_EOS_OVERRIDES.get(config)));
        clientProvidedProps.remove(config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Topics aren't transactional meaning a producer not using transactions and writing to a topic does not have an impact on a Kafka Streams application using EOS.  Enabling EOS in Kafka Streams means records are only processed once within Kafka Streams.  While you could use an idempotent producer within streams (it's not possible to use a transactional producer solely), based on the use case you are presenting here, I don't think you need to.

Comment: I don't want to mean that topic is transactional but data produce in topic are (with read_commited beahvior). It turns out that if when a Kafka Streams is configured with Processing guarantee EOS, no data are consume if its not been produced with a commit (beacause of the Isolation Level force to read_committed)